# How to animate 2 layouts with margins from top to bottom and from bottom to top

Tags: android, animation, layout

I'm trying to create an app that has 2 layouts: one on top and one on bottom. I want that when you click on a layout, 2 change of position and one climb and the other lower.

But I have several problems:

- layout 2 disturbs their position
- 2 layouts will disappear from the screen before putting on

How can I fix my mistakes? Thank you

[image]
[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout rl_footer, rl_footer2;
ImageView iv_header, iv_header2;
boolean isBottom = true;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    rl_footer2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer2);

    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
    iv_header2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow2);

    iv_header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isBottom) {

                SlideToAbove1();
                SlideToDown2();
                isBottom = false;

            } else {

                SlideToDown1();
                SlideToAbove2();
                isBottom = true;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void SlideToAbove1() {

    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(600);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(20, 20, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });
}

public void SlideToAbove2() {

    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(600);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer2.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer2.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer2.getWidth(), rl_footer2.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, 20, 20, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rl_footer2.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });
}

public void SlideToDown1() {

    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(600);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 20);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });
}

public void SlideToDown2() {

    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(600);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer2.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer2.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer2.getWidth(), rl_footer2.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 20);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            rl_footer2.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0000" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#666666" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#666666" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed an animation subclass to do this exact thing. Here's the code:

```
public class MarginAnimation extends Animation
{
    private View mView;
    private int mTargetTopMargin;
    private int mTargetLeftMargin;

    private int mStartTopMargin;
    private int mStartLeftMargin;

    public MarginAnimation(View view, int targetTopMargin, int targetLeftMargin)
    {
        mView = view;
        mTargetTopMargin = targetTopMargin;
        mTargetLeftMargin = targetLeftMargin;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mView.getLayoutParams();
        mStartTopMargin = params.topMargin;
        mStartLeftMargin = params.leftMargin;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        // I assume the view is inside a RelativeLayout. Change as required.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mView.getLayoutParams();

        params.topMargin = (int)(mStartTopMargin + (mTargetTopMargin - mStartTopMargin) * interpolatedTime);
        params.leftMargin = (int)(mStartLeftMargin + (mTargetLeftMargin - mStartLeftMargin) * interpolatedTime);

        mView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MarginAnimation animation = new MarginAnimation(view, targetTopMargin, targetLeftMargin);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

I should note that animations which invoke layout changes aren't the most optimal choice in Android when it come to performance, but it should get the job done.

If you can, try performing an animation on `translationX/Y` and perform layout (`margin`) changes only in the beginning / end of the animation.